# How to locate image resources in Orchard

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, url, orchardcms

I want to get a link to image resource in a MVC view that is part of an Orchard module.

Googling a bit resulted in the following approach:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9256515/3936440

and its using `@Html.ResourceUrl()` in views to get the resource URL.

I wonder where the `ResourceUrl()` comes from as its not documented in MSDN and i cannot use it in my projects either.

Did someone used that approach already and can shed some light on whats missing here?

Update:

I figured it out. The following code works in connection with Orchard modules.

First you need to add a resource manifest to the Orchard module like so

```
public class ResourceManifest : Orchard.UI.Resources.IResourceManifestProvider
{
  public void BuildManifests(Orchard.UI.Resources.ResourceManifestBuilder aBuilder)
  {
    Orchard.UI.Resources.ResourceManifest lManifest = aBuilder.Add();

    string lModulePath = "~/Modules/YourModuleName";

    lManifest.DefineResource("ProfilePicture", "User1").SetUrl(lModulePath + "/Images/User1.png");
  }
}
```

Then you extend the Html object:

```
// This class adds so called "extension methods" to class System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
  // This method retrieves the URL of a resource defined in ResourceManifest.cs via the Orchard resource management system
  public static string ResourceUrl(this System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper aHtmlHelper, string aResourceType, string aResourceName)
  {
    // note:
    //  resolving Orchard.UI.Resources.IResourceManager via work context of orchard because
    //    - calling System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current.GetService() does not work as it always returns null at this point
    //    - constructor parameter injection is not allowed in static classes
    //    - setting the resource manager from another class that uses constructor parameter injection does not work as it causes a "circular component dependency "
    Orchard.WorkContext lWorkContext = Orchard.Mvc.Html.HtmlHelperExtensions.GetWorkContext(aHtmlHelper);

    Orchard.UI.Resources.IResourceManager lResourceManager = (Orchard.UI.Resources.IResourceManager)lWorkContext.Resolve<Orchard.UI.Resources.IResourceManager>();
    if (lResourceManager != null)
    {
      Orchard.UI.Resources.RequireSettings lSettings = new Orchard.UI.Resources.RequireSettings { Type = aResourceType, Name = aResourceName, BasePath = aResourceType };

      Orchard.UI.Resources.ResourceDefinition lResource = lResourceManager.FindResource(lSettings);
      if (lResource != null)
      {
        Orchard.UI.Resources.ResourceRequiredContext lContext = new Orchard.UI.Resources.ResourceRequiredContext { Resource = lResource, Settings = lSettings };

        string lAppBasePath = System.Web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath;

        return lContext.GetResourceUrl(lSettings, lAppBasePath);
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

and then you can write:

```
<img src="@Html.ResourceUrl("ProfilePicture", "User1")" />
```

in an Orchard module view to get appropriate image link for User1.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Nah, i didn't understand what the author wrote on first reading, ResourceUrl() is a so called extension method of the System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper class. Problem solved.

Comment: This looks overkill. What's wrong with putting the image in the Content/Images folder of the module, and then use Url.Content?

Comment: @Bertrand Le Roy Simply putting the images in a folder as you suggested does not work in connection with the routes i provide for the module. Thus i came up with the centralized resource approach to avoid writing ~/Modules/YourModuleName/Images/MyImage over and over again.

Comment: How does it not work? Registered resources are for resources that must be re-usable across modules, not to simplify route resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ResourceUrl()` is a custom `HtmlHelper` extension.

The code that you need to implement it is included in the answer you have linked.

You simply need to create a static class that contains the method code.

[**Asp.net article on how to create custom html helpers**](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)

PS: Make sure you import your namespace into the view with `@using YourNamespace` or add it to the `System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper` class.

Comment: Yep, everything correct BUT its not that easy in Orchard. I updated my question with the code needed to get this working in an Orchard module.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy Nice one. :)